# psubscribe with '*' pattern a bad idea?

Tags: redis, routes, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to set up some pubsub stuff with redis and node.js, and I was wondering if it would be a bad idea to `psubscribe` to the `*` pattern (all channels) and then just handle "channel routing" on my own within that message handler.

Primarily, my concern is for performance and scalability in terms of volume. I think I can guess that this might be unwieldy to manage if I had a growing number of channels with differing purposes. Unless I built a very good framework/abstraction for it.

I think I've made my question clear enough. Additionally, if there are existing frameworks designed to solve this problem, I'd be curious to hear about them in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a BAD idea to do that, unless you want to achieve something that Redis pubsub doesn't support, e.g. subscribe to channels with regular expression.

- There's no need to do the routing on client side, you can just depend on the server side routing.
- If your Redis instance is shared with other applications (although NOT recommended), you might get many noises, i.e. messages belongs to other applications.
- Also, if your Redis is enabled with [keyspace notification](https://redis.io/topics/notifications), and you psubscribe to "*", you might get too many messages.